# NG Serve with a VirtualPath or subdirectory

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We run our angular application in IIS as a virtual application "myapplication"

In our angular app I have set in index.html:

```
<base href="/myapplication/">
```

It is working in IIS fine. However now NG serve does not work. As it can't find all the bundles under http://localhost/myapplication/ because the CLI isn't running under that path.

I have tried

```
ng serve --base-href /myapplication/
```

and browse to http://localhost:4200/myapplication/

I still see the same errors.

How do I tell the CLI to serve the application under "http://localhost:4200/myapplication/"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the base href to just this:

```
<base href="/">
```

That sets the default for development time.

Then when you build for production, use:

```
ng serve --base-href /myapplication/
```

That will set it correctly when it builds the files for deployment.

Comment: ahhhh I was understanding it backwards! Thanks Deborah!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to differentiate the base paths used for routing and assets, you can use both `--base-href` and `--deploy-url`:

```
ng serve --base-href /myapplication --deploy-url /static
```

Your application should now be accessible at http://localhost:4200/myapplication while your static files will be served from  http://localhost:4200/static.

You can also add these as [`baseHref`](https://nx.dev/angular/cli/build#basehref) and [`deployUrl`](https://nx.dev/angular/cli/build#deployurl) in your `workspace.json` config file.

Most of the time `baseHref` should be enough though.